Will Xamarin forms application support IOS 18?
I have a Xamarin application which is live on app store and it is working perfectly fine on IOS 17 and lower versions. But when I upgraded my iPhone from IOS 17 to IOS 18 beta version. I opened my application, it opens but the screen is freezing, I am not able to perform any clicks.
So what workaround can I do to make my app run on IOS 18 apart from migrating my application from Xamarin forms to .NET MAUI?
but when I switch to another application and come back to my application it is working perfect.

The short answer is no, the long answer is Xamarin does not exist anymore, especially in the eyes of MS, they don't care if all the people using Xamarin have such issues, you have to move it to MAUI before it's too late...

No. The support already ended and repo has been archived. So, no more support for Xamarin, please migrate it to .NET Maui

Xamarin support ended on May 1, 2024 for all Xamarin SDKs including
Xamarin.Forms. Android API 34 and Xcode 15 SDKs (iOS and iPadOS 17,
macOS 14) are the final versions Xamarin targets from existing Xamarin
SDKs (that is, no new APIs are planned).

